# Javascript coding seems to stall

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry for the vague title but here is my problem :

I have an HTML table that I am generating from Javascript, this is fine and the table generates as expected with no problems.

When the user clicks on a cell it will highlight that cell (or un-highlight if the cell is highlighted), this again works fine.

We then needed the ability to drag over the cells (whilst the mouse is down) and highlight the cells they hovered, this I managed to do but it was not the best solution so it was asked if we could select a cell, then hover to another cell and all the cells in between become highlighted.

```
For example :

Start Cell = Row 1, Cell 1

End Cell = Row 3, Cell 3

Highlighted Cells = R1C1, R1C2, R1C3, R2C1, R2C2, R2C3, R3C1, R3C2, R3C3.
```

I have managed to sort of get this solution to work, here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujhUm/1/) to show the solution, if you click on the first cell and hold the mouse down and drag to the last cell it works fine.

My Problem is that if you drag from the last cell (bottom left) to the top cell (top right) the highlighting effect seems to stall randomly until you are on row 2 or 3.

Is there any reason why this would be occurring? Is my code incorrect / inefficient for this?

I've been stuck with this for sometime and can't seem to find any reason why it would be occurring.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. - This solution **MUST** be a fully Javascript solution, jQuery cannot be used for this solution unfortunately as we require this to be a single HTML File and must be possible to use without an Internet Connection.

Comment: Nitpick: jQuery is JavaScript. If you wanted to use it, you could put it in the page using an inline script tag.

Comment: Fair point, think I'm just having a dumb day today. But still I'd assume this problem would persist? I'll give it a go with jQuery.

Comment: Changing the available parts of the code to jQuery did not fix the problem, the same issues occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you extract rowNum and cellNum, in ClickCell function, you have to convert value to interger:

```
var RowNum = parseInt(cellID.substring(1, cellID.indexOf('C')), 10);
var CellNum = parseInt(cellID.substring(cellID.indexOf('C') + 1, cellID.length), 10);
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, but this does not solve the issue I am getting.

Comment: realy? I juste test and it's seams to work perfectly I have update the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ujhUm/4/

Comment: I'm sorry, having some stupid moments today... This now works fine, thanks a lot :)